# Python: Why do my module variables lose their content?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

Please have a look at that "module":

```
"""Module a"""

a = None
b = None


def gna():
    global a
    if a is None:
        global b
        a = 7
        b = "b"
    print("in a.py: a={}".format(a))
    print("in a.py: b={}".format(b))
```

I would have thought that calling gna() from another module would initialise the variables:

```
"""Module b"""

from a import a, b, gna

print("in b.py: a={}".format(a))
print("in b.py: b={}".format(b))

gna()

print("in b.py: a={}".format(a))
print("in b.py: b={}".format(b))
```

But:

```
% python3 b.py
in b.py: a=None
in b.py: b=None
in a.py: a=7
in a.py: b=b
in b.py: a=None
in b.py: b=None
```

And I don't really get why a and b are None after calling gna...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you import a name into a module, the name becomes local. You should import module `a` instead of importing variables `a` and `b` from module `a` so that module `b` would be able to access the same references to variables `a` and `b` whose values the function `gna` modifies:

```
"""Module b"""

import a

print("in b.py: a={}".format(a.a))
print("in b.py: b={}".format(a.b))

a.gna()

print("in b.py: a={}".format(a.a))
print("in b.py: b={}".format(a.b))
```